# Variables.less on Twitter returns a blank css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I', using bootstrap 3 and I have an issue with the file variables.less. I build bootstrap.less perfectlly but when I build variables.less return me a blank css. Only with that file, any body knows why?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?  Have you modified the file in any way?

Comment: Apparently everything is fine when I build the file(without error messages). But when I open the page in the browser all the styles of bootstrap stays there. like I didn't change nothing. And I only modified the variables.less file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't build `variables.less` separately, because there is nothing there to produce a valid CSS other than (what the filename says) variables, that are not supported by CSS. You should **just compile the `bootstrap.less` file**, it includes the `variables.less` (and all other required less files).

Comment: I build the bootstrap.less file with some modifications but the styles doesn't apply on the page. It's linked and the console shows the correct css but the page not.